# How to send data from one website to another website in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let, I have developed two websites: **A** and **B**.
I have created a link on the react **A** website.
And I want to get the link from the react **B** website.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can send data through query parameter if you have data which is in the form of URL friendly format.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the link from the react B website by parameter from URL

Answer (score 0):

Are your trying get data from "website" (parse HTML) or data from server using REST API?

In option 2, your server should return header with:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

to execute request from another domain.

Then you can use fetch method to get data from server like this:

```
       fetch( ConfigX.restApi + "/r,get_training" , {
          method: 'POST', 
          body: JSON.stringify(dataPost),            
      })
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then(json => {
      
           //console.log(JSON.stringify(json) );
       

           this.setState({
              rows: json.rows,
              result: json.result
           });      
         
      });
```